# Cakephp: how to pass values into a javascript file?

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I have some javascript that is being included in a view and I used inkedmn's method in this thread:
[adding-page-specific-javascript-to-each-view-in-cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425084/adding-page-specific-javascript-to-each-view-in-cakephp)

So I now have the following code in my view:

```
$this->set('jsIncludes',array('google'));   // this will link to /js/google.js
```

But I need to pass some values from the view into the javascript file and I'm unsure of how to accomplish this.

Update: I guess one option would be to echo the values in the php file, enclose in a div tag, and then use a getElementById() in the javascript code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to inject a <script> tag directly into the HTML with the data you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mynum = <?php echo intval($num); ?>;
var mystring = "<?php echo addslashes($string); ?>";
var myarray = <?php echo json_encode(array("one" => 1, "two" => 2)); ?>;
</script>
```

Any javascript elsewhere should be able to use these variables.

**Note:** if the code using this data runs earlier in the page, they obviously won't see these variables yet. If that's the case, either ensure that your data is loaded first, or you can delay the code from running until the page is fully loaded, using either setTimeout() or a document.onready event.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have an additional requirement for the user to not see the values of these variables in rendered html page source. The values are kind of secure. Any idea how this can be accomplished ?

Comment: @akskap I don't think it's possible; at best you can obfuscate the data and make it more difficult to read. There isn't a way to provide data to the browser that the user can't see if they are sufficiently determined. Anything that needs to be 100% secret must live entirely server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some code that runs automatically? You could wrap it inside a function, and pass the function the necessary parameters.

For example, let's you currently have the following code in `my-script.js`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  alert('My favorite fruits are apples, and my favorite color is red.');
}
```

Wrap it in a function like this:

```
function initialize(args) {
  window.onload = function() {
    alert('My favorite fruits are ' + args.fruit +
     ', and my favorite color is ' + args.color + '.');
    }
  }
```

Then, output a `<script>` element using PHP somewhere after `my-script.js` is loaded, and call the function. Here's an example output:

```
<script>
  initialize({fruit: 'apples', color: 'red'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Js->set('varname',$value);
```

from js file

```
var myvar = window.app.varname;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are following step:

1) Include the js helper in AppController.php

```
public $helpers = array('Js');
```

2) Now Declare js variable in ctp file 
Like that way :

```
$state = 'rajasthan';
$this->Js->set('state_name',$state);
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('onDomReady' => false));
```

3) Now Use this js vairable "state_name" in js file 
Like that way :

```
console.log(window.app.state_name);
var state = window.app.state_name;
```