# Using php variables in js files

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a view file called edit.ctp and a js file called edit.js.
On edit.ctp i'm calling edit.js like that:

```
$this->Html->script('edit', array('inline' => false));
```

js files its being included right so i have a issue to use php markups like this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061291/cakephp-how-to-pass-values-into-a-javascript-file)

probably because the file is .js is not able to accept php makups.

So what is the best way to work with php markups on js files?

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to declare the variable globally, and set it from the onload event that runs after the page has loaded:

```
<script>

var your_variable;

function init() {
  your_variable = document.getElementById('xxx1');
}

</script>

<body onload="init();">
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is just change the name of the js files to `edit.php` if you do this I would make sure to include:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/javascript"); ?>
```

While it might not be strictly needed I think it's a good practice.

Your other options would be to change your servers config filter all js through php (from a performance standpoint ... probably not a good idea)

Hope this helps.