# Stripe implementaion in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, stripe-payments, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to implement the latest version of stripe payment in a CakePHP project. I'm beginning in CakePHP.

I read the doc but the thing is that, I have to combine JavaScript and CakePHP controller.

My question is how to fetch client_secret in a Javacript function to make it look like stripe doc authorize.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cakephp: how to pass values into a javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061291/cakephp-how-to-pass-values-into-a-javascript-file)

Comment: Thanks @BadHorsie but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last comment what I understand is, you have a data lets say **$secret_key** which is available in controller and we need to use **$secret_key** in JavaScript. If I understand correctly, here are the two ways we can follow:

Set $secret_key in view: i.e **$this->set(compact('secret_key'));** in the controller method. Thus it will be available in view.

1. set $secret_key in a hidden input. like

   <input type="hidden" name="secret_key" id="secret_key" value="< ?= $secret_key ?>"

then access it through JavaScript.

```
var secret_key = document.getElementById("secret_key").value;
```

2. Set directly $secret_key directly in JavaScript variable.

`var secret_key = '<?= $secret_key?>'`;

You should write no.2 code in view as in .js file php text is not workable.

Note: in input field value, I put an extra space before ? as Stack overflow somehow hiding it.Please remove that extra space on testing time.

Answer (score 0):

The request itself would be via a normal `fetch` request on the frontend. [0]

On the backend/endpoint that you're calling (the controller), you'd use `stripe-php` [1] to retrieve the PaymentIntent and look at its client_secret value. [2]

[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have already read those documents but I'm still having a problem to implent it. My PaymentIntent is made inside my controller and it should return a secret Key. And that secret key should be use inside a JS function according to stripe Doc. How am I suppose to send or fetch that secret Key inside my JS function. That's my question